# New elementary OS install boots to terminal

Tags: release-freya

I've been using elementary OS for a while with no problems however I'm having trouble getting it going on my new laptop on which I've installed Freya as the sole OS. It's a high spec machine: i7, SSD etc etc. The problem is that it's booting to a command prompt (tty1) rather than boot in to the GUI. I think I saw a post about this a while ago but now I can't find it. I've had trouble with vanilla Ubuntu in the past where I've had to put nomodeset in the grub file in order to get into the GUI and then load the videos drivers, which was a long shot and isn't getting me anywhere in this instance.

A quick summary of the machine: It has a GeForce GTX960M (2gb DDR5), a quad i7-4910MQ CPU, 16gb of Kingston Hyper-X RAM and a 500gb Samsung SSD.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please add some information to your post? Especially about your GPU and what graphic driver (and how did you install the driver) you are using?

Comment: Sure, it's has a GeForce GTX960M (2gb DDR5). I've not installed any drivers for it yet because I can't get into the UI and so as it is it's a completely fresh installation. It also has a quad i7-4910MQ CPU and 16gb of Kingston Hyper-X RAM and a 500gb Samsung SSD. Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe it does help (I'm not sure yet), but please edit your question to contain this information where it's more obvious for people who want to help you :)

Comment: it appears that X-server cannot start. I bet on driver problem here. Download the driver from a command line, and install it in the text mode. You can download drivers for linux from the website itself. If you have problems downloading the drivers from the command line - download it to a USB drive on some other machine, and later attach to your computer. Driver is a *.run file - it means you should just give it execution permissions and launch as a binary, and follow on-screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks v_pavel. I've managed to install the GeForce drivers from the command line and now it just boots to a blank screen. I'll keep trawling the web and see what I can find.

Comment: @Rob too bad it didn't solve the issue completely... Can you post contents of the X-server logs? it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

May not necessarily be your issue; but I had this issue with Luna while back on my laptop - the graphics driver was not installed, I had to manually install it.

This guide may help:
http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/